# How do I compare one column of a file with another column of another file using awk?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have two files like below:

file1.txt

```
2018-03-14 13:23:00 CID [72883359]
2018-03-14 13:23:00 CID [275507537]
2018-03-14 13:23:00 CID [275507539]
2018-03-14 13:23:00 CID [207101094]
2018-03-14 13:23:00 CID [141289821]
```

and file2.txt

```
2018-03-14 13:23:00 CID [207101072]
2018-03-14 13:23:00 CID [275507524]
2018-03-14 13:23:00 CID [141289788]
2018-03-14 13:23:00 CID [72883352]
2018-03-14 13:23:01 CID [72883359]
2018-03-14 13:23:00 CID [275507532]
```

I need to compare 4th colum of first file with 4th colum of 2nd file. I am using below command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4]=$1" "$2" "$3; next} ($4 in a) {print a[$4],$4,$1,$2}' file1.txt file2.txt>file3.txt
```

Its output is like below.

```
2018-03-14 13:23:00 CID [72883359] 2018-03-14 13:23:01
```

Above command works properly , but problem is file1 and file2 are huge and has some 20k lines and hence above command is taking time.

I want if a match is found , than it should skip the remaining column and go for next, means some kind of break statement . Please help.

Below is my script.

```
#!/bin/sh

cron=1;

for((j = $cron; j >= 1; j--))
do
    d1=`date -d "$date1  $j min ago" +%Y-%m-%d`
    d2=`date -d 'tomorrow' '+%Y-%m-%d'`
    
    t1=`date -d "$date1  2 min ago" +%R`
    t2=`date -d "$date1  1 min ago" +%R`
    t3=`date --date="0min" +%R`
done


cat /prd/firewall/logs/lwsg_event.log | egrep "$d1|$d2" | egrep "$t1|$t2|$t3" |  grep 'SRIR' | awk -F ' ' '{print $1,$2,$4,$5}'>file1.txt


cat /prd/firewall/logs/lwsg_event.log | egrep "$d1|$d2" | egrep "$t1|$t2|$t3" | grep 'SRIC' | awk -F ' ' '{print $1,$2,$4,$5}'>file2.txt


awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4]=$1" "$2" "$3; next} ($4 in a) {print a[$4],$4,$1,$2}' file1.txt file2.txt>file3.txt

cat file3.txt | while read LINE
do
    f1=`echo $LINE | cut -f 1 -d " "`
    f2=`echo $LINE | cut -f 2 -d " "`
    
    String1=$f1" "$f2
    
    f3=`echo $LINE | cut -f 5 -d " "`
    f4=`echo $LINE | cut -f 6 -d " "`
    
    String2=$f3" "$f4
    
    
    f5=`echo $LINE | cut -f 3 -d " "`
    f6=`echo $LINE | cut -f 4 -d " "`
    
    String3=$f5" "$f6
    
    StartDate=$(date -u -d "$String1" +"%s")
    FinalDate=$(date -u -d "$String2" +"%s")
    echo "Diff for $String3 :" `date -u -d "0 $FinalDate sec - $StartDate sec" +"%H:%M:%S"` >final_output.txt
done
```

`final_output.txt` will be

```
Diff for CID [142298410] : 00:00:01
Diff for CID [273089511] : 00:00:00
Diff for CID [273089515] : 00:00:00
Diff for CID [138871787] : 00:00:00
Diff for CID [273089521] : 00:00:00
Diff for CID [208877371] : 00:00:00
Diff for CID [138871793] : 00:00:00
Diff for CID [138871803] : 00:00:00
Diff for CID [273089526] : 00:00:00
Diff for CID [273089545] : 00:00:00
Diff for CID [208877406] : 00:00:02
Diff for CID [208877409] : 00:00:01
Diff for CID [138871826] : 00:00:00
Diff for CID [74659680] : 00:00:00
```

Comment: could you explain `skip the remaining colum and go for next`? it is not clear... regarding the cmd you've tried, looks the best possible for this case..

Comment: skip means , if amatch is found , then no need to traverse whole colum of file2. If a match is found than read another value from 4th colum of file1 and find it in 4th colum of file2.  So that script can complete its work fast.

Comment: sorry I still don't understand.. the script is reading each line of both files only once...

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4]=$0;next} ($4 in a){print a[$4],$1,$2}' file1.txt  file2.txt
```

Comment: no @ravindersingh13 , it did not help , script is still taking same time as before.

Comment: @sunil.tanwar, if a line is loaded in memory then only it can compare it with other file's line. Do you want to match only VERY FIRST match for any line and exit out of script? If no then this above should be good. Also please let us know how big files are? run above command with `time` command before it and share the timings too with it, please get back to us with these details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the `join` command? Not many people seem to know about join.

```
NAME
       join - join lines of two files on a common field

SYNOPSIS
       join [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2
```

Comment: how to join ? I want to join based on my fourth colum of file1.txt

Comment: join -j 4 file1.txt file2.txt

Comment: Unfortunately `join` has one drawback: the columns on which to join have to be sorted. So first you have to do something like: `sort --key=4 file1.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Your overall script reads the same file multiple times and contains a large number of other inefficiencies.

Without proper input to test with, it's hard to verify this, but here is a refactoring which should hopefully at least suggest a good direction for further exploration.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

cron=1;

for((j = $cron; j >= 1; j--))
do
    # Replace obsolescent `backticks` with $(modern command substitution) syntax
    d1=$(date -d "$date1  $j min ago" +%Y-%m-%d)
    d2=$(date -d 'tomorrow' '+%Y-%m-%d')
    
    t1=$(date -d "$date1  2 min ago" +%R)
    t2=$(date -d "$date1  1 min ago" +%R)
    t3=$(date --date="0min" +%R)
done

# Avoid useless cat and useless grep, fold everything into one Awk script
# See also http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html
awk -v d="$d1|$d2" -v t="$t1|$t2|$t3" '
    $0 !~ d {next} $0 !~ t { next }
    { o = "" }
    /SRIR/ { o="file1.txt" }
    /SRIC/ { o="file2.txt" }
    o { {print $1,$2,$4,$5 > o; o="" }' /prd/firewall/logs/lwsg_event.log

awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4]=$1" "$2" "$3; next} ($4 in a) {print a[$4],$4,$1,$2}' file1.txt file2.txt>file3.txt

# Avoid uppercase for private variables
# Use read -r always
# Let read split the line
while read -r f1 f2 f5 f6 f3 f4 
do
    String1=$f1" "$f2
    String2=$f3" "$f4
    String3=$f5" "$f6
    
    StartDate=$(date -u -d "$String1" +"%s")
    FinalDate=$(date -u -d "$String2" +"%s")
    echo "Diff for $String3 :" $(date -u -d "0 $FinalDate sec - $StartDate sec" +"%H:%M:%S")
done <file3.txt >final_output.txt
```

I would guess that the main bottleneck was that you processed the log file multiple times, not so much in the small Awk fragment you run on the results which you asked for help with.

This could still probably be refactored into a single Awk script. If you have GNU Awk, you should be able to do the `date` calculations in Awk, too.